# Python multi-threading/processing module for tasks with dependencies requiring sequencing

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, dependencies, multiprocessing

I'm in the process of implementing a Python module that provides a thread (or process) pool that can handle processing tasks concurrently that are potentially dependent on each other.  For example, in the case of an order management system, you could place an order, place another order, cancel the second order, place a third order, and then cancel the first order - all order placements can be processed at the same time, but the cancellations can't happen at the same time as their respective orders and must happen after their order placements are completed.  I have come up with a good general purpose solution to problems like this and wanted to use it as my first open source contribution.

Before spending too much time on this I just wanted to know if something like this already exists.  Does anyone know of an existing Python package that does this?  Would this be useful to anyone?

Comment: For anyone interested, I've started a project for this on GitHub - https://github.com/mikecoop83/pysequen

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at [dask](/questions/tagged/dask). It has different schedulers for multithreaded, multiprocessing, and distributed computing which reuse threads and processes through `TaskPool` and `Pool` respectively. You can build any task dependencies (direct acyclic graphs - DAGs) with it. Though, I'm not sure about cancellation support but you can implement it manually in your tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the info on dask. From what I briefly read, it looks like you submit the entire DAG as a single set of a tasks (with dependencies) to be executed.  This handles the scenario where the producer is aware of all the dependencies. In what I was going to implement, the producer doesn't know, but the tasks implement an "interface" where they can be "asked" if they can execute at the same time as another task. This way, the producer doesn't need to know the dependencies and the scheduler handles making sure things are executed in the right order.  Does that make sense?